# Есть ли у карт google maps api функционал похожий на ObjectManager из yandex maps?

Tags: google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, google-maps, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как выяснилось для стран Европы карты Яндекс хуже детализированы чем карты гугл, поэтому придётся использовать карты гугл для отображения. Но у яндекса есть замечательный функционал по группировке точек ObjectManager, знает ли кто либо есть ли у google похожий функционал?

Answer (score 1):

В Google Maps это же - кластеризация
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering

Comment: справедливости ради, кластеризация - не совсем то же самое, т.к. требует добавить на карту сразу все точки. Менеджер объектов в API Яндекс.Карт позволяет, например, грузить только объекты в видимой области, благодаря чему в итоге позволяет отобразить без тормозов больше объектов.

Comment: да, кластеризация в Яндекс сделана сильнее... Можно разные объекты помещать в один кластер, и они будут группироваться в одном "бублике"))) Но в гугле так либо - нельзя сделать, либо я не знаю как )))

Comment: велосипед гугла, не обновлявшийся лет 5, - это убожество. Уж его сколько ни форкали, так и остался примитив.